# Filter DataGridView from datepicker

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGrid (dataGridView1) in a Windows Form.  dataGridView1 is populated from a business object when the form loads.  That works as expected:

```
bs.DataSource = oBadger_History.GetChild();
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

I have a dateTimePicker (dateTimePicker1) and on dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged, I want to filter the dataGridView1 results to only show results for the date (v_issue_date) selected in dateTimePicker1.   I have tried the following (using Filter). .but can't seem to get it to work.  Maybe a second pair of eyes will help?

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "M/d/yyyy";
cs.DataSource = bs.Filter = string.Format("v_issue_date LIKE '{0}%' ",  dateTimePicker1.Text);

dataGridView1.DataSource = cs;
dataGridView1.Update();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

And please keep in mind that I am relatively new to c#.  I did a search (both here and google) and although there was some good information, it was not directly related to what I am trying to achieve.

In the above scenario, the DataGridView1 does refresh - but the refresh does not show the filter applied.

Just to rule out the possibility of a date type mismatch - I made a very simple filter - and still, the DataGridView1 did refresh but did not display filtered data.

```
BindingSource cs = new BindingSource();

cs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
cs.Filter = "[v_firstname] = 'Jose'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = cs;
dataGridView1.Update();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

These failed attempts mock most of the examples I have seen online . . so I am not sure why the filter does not get applied.

EDIT - *********

Keeping it very simple, I have posted the load and the event below:

```
private void ChildReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = oBadger_History.GetChild();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.Filter = string.Format("v_issue_date = '{0:yyyy/MM/dd}'", dateTimePicker1.Value);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs.Filter;
        dataGridView1.Update();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

In the above sample, the table refreshes but it always comes back empty.  No Matches found.  Not sure what the issue is.    v_issue_date is a date type field.  I have placed stops in debug and I can verify that the dateTimePicker.Value is in the table.  Not sure why I can't pull a match out.

Edit 2 **********

This is the business object that I use to fill DataGridView1.

```
public daBindingList<Badger_History> GetChild()
    {

        BadgerContext cn = (BadgerContext)this.context;
        var entityKist = cn.Badger_History.Where(b => b.v_child == "Child").ToList();
        this.EntityList = new daBindingList<Badger_History>(entityKist);
        return this.EntityList;

    }
```

Comment: It is unclear why the code is introducing a second `BindingSource`… `BindingSource cs = new BindingSource(); cs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;` ? Is there some reason you do not use the original `BindingSource` for the filter? Also, I am confident you cannot use “LIKE” or a “wildcard” (%) with “DATES”. LIKE and wildcards only work with strings and not numeric/date values. You will need to use “>,<,=” values to filter a date.

Comment: Also, on the filter string the code is using the `DataTimePickers` `Text` property which is a “string” … the value should be a `DateTime` object, therefore you need to use the DTP’s `Value` property. I had success by removing the unnecessary second binding source and used the following filter sting on the original binding source… `bs.Filter = string.Format("Date = '{0:yyyy/MM/dd}'", dateTimePicker1.Value);`

Comment: @JohnG - There was no specific reason that I created a second BindingSource for the filter - other than I have been desperate and trying anything at all.  I am still having problems with trying to implement your recommendations . I will clean up my code and repost an edit in a moment.

Comment: Change the line `dataGridView1.DataSource = bs.Filter;` TO `dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;` … also the Refresh and Update are unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnG -  The reason I had set the Datasource = bs.Filter is because when I set Datasource = bs; The datagridview data never changes.  It's as if the filter does not exist.  I get the original FULL bs Datasource not the filtered version.

Comment: I can only guess that the posted code is not getting fired. Put a break point in the code to make sure it is getting executed. I base this assumption on the DTPs `ValueChanged_1` event... is there another DTP event called `ValueChanged`? If so, then you need to clean that up.

Answer (score 1):

After spending far too much time trying to get the bs.Filter to work properly, I resolved it by going in a different direction.

Because, no matter how hard I tried, I could not remove the time from the datetime value . . . I decided to use a greater than date and less than date.

```
DateTime StartDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
dt = dt.AddDays(0);
dt = dt.AddDays(1);

bs.DataSource = oBadger_History.EntityList.Where(a => a.v_child == "Child" && a.v_issue_date >= StartDate && a.v_issue_date <= dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

This does work and accomplishes my needs.  I am sure there is a better way - but I ran out of time.

thank you @JohnG for all of your patience and help. I really do appreciate your efforts.